# How can I have my own MvM server to play with my friends?

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration, tf2-mann-vs-machine

I want to create it, because I've made my own MvM wave and I want my friends to try it out.

How do I load my custom MvM wave into a server that my friends and I can play?

Comment: @Virusbomb That answer nearly answers this one. The difference is that it does not specify mvm maps in instruction 4. https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/List_of_maps (look for maps prefixed by 'mvm_')

Comment: @Bonnito I found [this guide](https://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/1/882957625821803632/) that might help.

Comment: Virusbomb, I took a look at that before I create this one.

Comment: I would say the other question is related, but as this one talks about MvM, and a custom MvM wave to boot (rather than just running up a server with a standard map and adding bots), I don't think it's a duplicate per se.

Comment: MvM does require more configuration than the other game modes do.  It also requires setting maxplayers to 32 (6 player slots, 22 bot slots, and 4 spectator slots).

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try all methods of yours. If it works, I'll let you play, too. If you want to.

Comment: This is most definitely not a duplicate. There is a distinct difference between MVM and playing a standard match with bots, plus the linked question mentions nothing about using custom .pop files.